# change dropdown selected value based on textbox value in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a textbox and selected option list of 4 options like below...

```
<select id="select2" class="form-control">
                <option value="pre">Pre</option>
                <option value="rep" selected="selected">Rep</option>
                <option value="new">New</option>
                <option value="dec">Dec</option>
              </select>
```

and a textbox where user input some keywords and based on keywords i want to change selected option in above option list

```
<td id="fpv_col1"  contenteditable="">decorating and repair work</td>
```

main value for selction comes from php and ajax based on user input
so i just want to set selected value in above option list

below is my jquery code

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#fpv_col1', function(event) {
    var desc_text = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'php/fpv_lbyl_prediction.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                    value1:desc_text,

            },
            dataType:'text',
            success: function(data){
                $("#error_msg").fadeIn();
                $("#error_msg").html("<strong>Success!</strong> "+data);
                //$('select#select2 option').removeAttr('selected');
                //$('select#select2').find('option[value='+data+']').attr("selected",true);

                $('select#select2 option').removeAttr('selected').filter('[value='+data+']').attr('selected', true);  
            }
        });

event.preventDefault();

});
```

my jquery code works fine, it set selected option but not displaying selected option, it saw using inspect

Comment: Are you using any plugin such as `select2`? have you tried `$('#select2').val(data);`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#otherCategory').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
      $('#category').val(1);
    } else if ($(this).val() > 0) {
      $('#category').val(2);
    } else {
      $('#category').val(0);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="category" name="category">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Clear</option>
  <option value="2">UnClear</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="otherCategory" name="otherCategory">
```